# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer error when trying to deploy Vaadin WAR to Apache server

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

I'm running Vaadin version 24.2.3, Java version 21, Spring boot 3.0.5, and Apache Server 10.  When I try deploying the my project's WAR, I am getting the error:  *java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer*

I'm not sure where it is finding javax/servlet/SerletContainerInitializer as the versions listed above all should have been converted to the jakarta namespace.

Here is my POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <!-- Project from https://start.vaadin.com/project/e19d7d7f-cd4a-427d-814f-eccc10f31ea2 -->
    <groupId>org.mrpc</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrpc-admin</artifactId>
    <name>mrpc-admin</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>24.2.3</vaadin.version>
        <selenium.version>4.8.3</selenium.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.5</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.parttio</groupId>
            <artifactId>line-awesome</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench-junit5</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>CommonUtilities</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5796</jvmArguments>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <dependencies>
                <!-- Exclude development dependencies from production -->
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                    <exclusions>
                        <exclusion>
                            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                            <artifactId>vaadin-dev</artifactId>
                        </exclusion>
                    </exclusions>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

EDIT - Added stack trace

```
19-Dec-2023 16:15:49.515 SEVERE [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [D:\Tomcat10.1\webapps\mrpc-admin-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:686)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:712)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:975)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1952)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:776)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:426)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1708)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1098)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1301)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1283)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:572)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:358)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
                at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mrpc-admin-1.0-SNAPSHOT]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:419)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:186)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
                ... 24 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1027)
                at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2352)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:800)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1317)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
                at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:235)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:206)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1838)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1303)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:991)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:304)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:114)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4766)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:171)
                ... 25 more
        Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)
                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165)
                ... 44 more
```

Comment: Doesn't the full stacktrace give an indication, where it is coming from?

Comment: Not that I can see.  I've added the stack trace to the original question.

Comment: Which exact server version are you using? If you're using Apache Tomcat 10.0, you need to upgrade to 10.1 or later. https://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html

Comment: It is Tomcat 10.1.